# SQL Scalar function over several tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm very new at Sql-functions, and would like some pointers as to why my function is not behaving as I thought it would..

My database has a UserLogin table, which contains all users Email, among other things.
It then has a table for Customers, Teachers and Advisors, an ID in either of these 3 tables refer to an ID in the UserLogin table. The structure is debatable, but what I have settled on.

The purpose of my function is to find a users name, given his ID.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetUserLoginName
(
-- Add the parameters 
@id int
)
RETURNS varchar
AS
BEGIN
Declare @firstName varchar
declare @lastName varchar

-- If an advisor exists with ID, find names in Advisor table.
if (exists(
select *
from Advisor
where ID = @id))
Begin

SET @firstName = (
select u.FirstName
from dbo.Advisor as u
WHERE u.ID = @id)

SET @lastName = (
select u.LastName
from dbo.Advisor as u
WHERE u.ID = @id)
End

-- Else if a customer exists with ID, find names in customer table.
else if (exists(
select *
from Customer
where ID = @id))
Begin

SET @firstName = (
select u.FirstName
from dbo.Customer as u
WHERE u.ID = @id)

SET @lastName = (
select u.LastName
from dbo.Customer as u
WHERE u.ID = @id)
End

-- Else if a Teacher exists with ID, find names in Teacher table.
else if (exists(
select *
from Teacher
where ID = @id))
Begin

SET @firstName = (
select u.FirstName
from dbo.Teacher as u
WHERE u.ID = @id)

SET @lastName = (
select u.LastName
from dbo.Teacher as u
WHERE u.ID = @id)
End

RETURN (@firstName + ' ' + @lastName)

END
```

The function is Returning "K" for the name "Karl Pedersen"...

Comment: That's because `varchar` without a size specification (e.g. `varchar(15)`) defaults to the *ever so useful* `varchar(1)` (except in conversion functions, because if there's anything better than a stupid default, it's having two different defaults that you have to remember)

Comment: Thanks alot, defining the varchar's lengths, solved the problem!

Comment: Although scalar functions can be horrible for performance if you are going to proceed with this you need to set both firstName and LastName variables in a single pass of the base table. The only thing you are doing with two separate queries is making this slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to defining the size of your varchars you could make this function a LOT simpler. Something along these lines.

C

```
REATE FUNCTION GetUserLoginName
(
    -- Add the parameters 
    @id int
)
RETURNS varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @FullName varchar(30)

    select @FullName = x.FullName
    from
    (
        select a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName as FullName
        from dbo.Advisor as a
        WHERE a.ID = @id

        union all

        select c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName
        from dbo.Customer as c
        WHERE c.ID = @id

        union all

        select t.FirstName + ' ' + t.LastName
        from dbo.Teacher as t
        WHERE t.ID = @id
    ) x

    return @FullName

end
```